# Function doesn't shows password in real time

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, tkinter, passwords

When I click show password it shows password but when I input 1 more letter in the entry box then that letter doesn't show up but when I input one more letter the previous letter shows up but the letter which I inputed just now doesn't show up So I want the code to update the password in the Show password label(show) in real time.

Code:

```
from tkinter import *
win = Tk()
no=2
def evod():
    global no
    no+=1
    
def showpwd(e):
    global no, t
    def bind():
        text1=t.get()
        btn2=Button(win, text="hide",command=hide)
        btn2.grid(row=0,column=1)
        show.config(text=text1)
        evod()
    def hide():
        show.config(text="")
        btn3=Button(win, text="show",command=bind)
        btn3.grid(row=0,column=1)
        evod()
    if no % 2==0:
        txt=t.get()
        btn2=Button(win, text="hide",command=hide)
        btn2.grid(row=0,column=1)
        show.config(text=txt)
    else:
        show.config(text="")
        btn=Button(win, text="show",command=bind)
        btn.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
def bind():
    show.config(text=t.get())
    ent.bind("<Key>", showpwd)
t = StringVar()
ent = Entry(win,show="*", textvariable=t)
ent.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
btn=Button(win, text="show",command=bind)
btn.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
show= Label(win,text="")
show.grid(row = 1, column = 0,sticky="w")
win.mainloop()
```

Comment: use `ent.bind("<KeyRelease>", showpwd)`

Comment: But now when I do backspace to the entrybox it doesn't update in my label (show)

Comment: It does check again. Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66531648/12198502) out